# AbstractController::Helpers::MissingHelperError in Rails::WelcomeController#index

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This is my error when running my first ruby app on a rails server. Sometimes, I manage to get through, and sometimes I get this error 60% of the time.

[My Code](https://github.com/benjaminsunderland/Pinteresting)

[My Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzwQR.png)

```
AbstractController::Helpers::MissingHelperError in Rails::WelcomeController#index
Missing helper file helpers/c:/users/benjamin/desktop/pinteresting/app/helpers/application_helper.rb_helper.rb

Rails.root: c:/Users/Benjamin/desktop/pinteresting
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:151:in `rescue in block in modules_for_helpers'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:148:in `block in modules_for_helpers'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:144:in `map!'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:144:in `modules_for_helpers'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/helpers.rb:93:in `modules_for_helpers'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:108:in `helper'
actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/railties/helpers.rb:17:in `inherited'
railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/welcome_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:263:in `const_get'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:263:in `block in constantize'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `each'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `inject'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `constantize'
activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:566:in `get'
```

Comment: Could you please post the code in your question instead? I get 404 when clicking on the link.

Comment: it says `Missing helper file helpers/c:/users/benjamin/desktop/pinteresting/app/helpers/application_helper.rb_helper.rb` - something is wrong with this path, because you wouldn't have a `helpers/c:` directory. What is the line of source code this originates from? Linking to a github repo is not sufficient for a StackOverflow question; you should include all the relevant code.

Comment: change your application name `Pinteresting` to `pinteresting`.

Comment: have u solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

**[SOLVED]** I had the same issue. what i realized is that it occurs when you are running a new rails application in a different directory on a different drive (e.g. D:/). I believe it is important you run it in the drive in which you installed ruby and devkit ***(Don't forget to install your devkit and run ruby dk.rb init followed by ruby dk.rb install).***

## Steps

1. Re-run gem install rails fresh
2. Run rails new [my-application-name] relative to your ruby installation folder
3. Run rails s or rails server
4. Yay! You got your rails application up and running

Comment: Your application could be on your drive c:/ (I named mine as Ruby, so i have C:/Ruby)